# Надо ли перестраивать предложение?

Tags: местоимение

Human Rights Watch обвиняет власти Сирии в массовых пытках и убийствах своих политических оппонентов.

Если не перестроить предложение, чтобы не было двусмысленности относительно того, чьи оппоненты, это будет считаться ошибкой? Даже если читатель и понимает правильно.

Human Rights Watch обвиняет власти Сирии в том, что они убивают своих политических оппонентов и подвергают их массовым пыткам?

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что можно исправить и без перестраивания предложения, ведь это речевая ошибка-лексическая: неправильно выбрано местоимение "своих".

Human Rights Watch обвиняет власти Сирии в массовых пытках и убийствах **их** политических оппонентов.

Comment: Не менее "неоднозначно". Чьих их? сирийцев или HRW